# Scrapy Mongodb duplicate key error E11000 pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000

Tags: python, django, mongodb, scrapy

I m a newbie to python, django, scrapy and mongodb
What i am trying to do? 
Trying to persist data from scrapy to a mongodb collection created via django. So scrapy can read the data from this collection and display on a page.

What have i done so far?

- Model in django

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    urls = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

- upon migration of the project following 0001_initial.py was generated, meaning django auto generated the field 'id'

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.8 on 2019-12-27 03:09

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Project',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('desc', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('urls', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
               # ('image', models.FilePathField(path='/img')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

- Following is my spider,  pipeline.py file

```
class ProjectspiderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = self.conn['djangodb']
        #self.collection = db['spiderCollection']
        self.collection = db['projects_project']

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

- This is my items.py

```
import scrapy

class ProjectspiderItem(scrapy.Item):

    _id = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

- Now when i try to run it my spider with `self.collection = db['spiderCollection']` in my pipelines. It runs successful.
- However when i change the collection to `self.collection = db['projects_project']`. It ends up the following error:

```
error raise DuplicateKeyError(error.get("errmsg"), 11000, error)
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: djangodb.projects_project index: __primary_key__ dup key: { id: null }
```

Will appreciate if any one could guide me either of the two options:

- how to add auto generated value for _id in my spider?
- Can we bypass autogenerated id in django or migrate by not generating autogenerated ids as in 0001_initial.py file?

thanks and appreciate heaps.

Comment: The error message indicates that the duplicate value was `null`, perhaps if you can determine what caused the ID to be null in the first place, you can prevent this issue?

Comment: The reason is i m not generating any ID from scrapy that may be persisting. As i m new to all this. Can you guide me what would be syntax to generate the autogenerate/auto increment id in my spider that would persist in this field.

Comment: hi all, can i somehow do auto increment in my items.py? any help with syntax would be great. all i m looking into my spider to generate unique id and persist data along with it in the mongodb. I guess that would be much efficient and less time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to generate the mongodb ObjectId yourself and let the DB autogenerate it for you. MongoDB generated _id will be unique and you can also retrieve it after saving your item. Just send the object to the database without _id field and mongodb will generate it for you.

Comment: yup solved it , i fixed my django not to generate additional objectID, but it got me into another problem which is out of scope of this ticket. Appreciate the support @Taimur Ahmed Qureshi